# Node server kickstart in Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I have this SPA hosted on Microsoft Azure. This need to refresh some dashboard data every 5 seconds. For this I created a nodejs service that keep requesting the data to the API and generating a local json to which all dashboard requests are pointed.

In this scenario, **my problem is this**: I'm using [forever js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to keep my node service alive. In my localhost it works perfectly, but when I upload it to azure, in dev evinronment, it keeps losing all my global dependencies and jobs every time the app resets.

So, **my question is**: is there a way in Azure that I can configure a "kickstart" node command, so that it runs every time my app restarts, or recover from a downtime?

Something like `npm i -g forever && forever start server.js` everytime the app is up.

---

I know that I can set, for example, [the node version for my app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/), that is resetted every time the app restarts. So I imagine that there may be some room for running this snippet, am I wrong?

Comment: I would like to know the reason for someone downvoting this post.

Comment: Azure App Service already uses **iisnode** (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/) to manage your `node.exe` processes, no need for **forever**. If you have to run some code before your Node app comes up, why not drop it in your app's entry point, right before you start listening for requests? If you need to keep state, don't keep it in memory, put it in a Redis cache or DocumentDB or Table storage, anything off-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

On Azure Web Apps, you can leverage [**WebJobs**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/), to create your custom scripts in your favorite language, and make it continuous run in background.

Azure unloads your site if it is idle for the standard 20 minute timeout, which can cause your webjobs do not work. So you also need enable the Always On* configuration setting for **Continuous WebJobs**.

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/ for more details.